# C/C++ va_list not returning arguments properly

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I have a problem with using va_list. The below code works for an int:

```
main() {
  int f1=1;
  float** m = function(n,f1);
}

float** function(int n,...) {

  va_list mem_list;
  va_start(mem_list, n);
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++) {
      //m[i][j]=va_arg(mem_list,float);
      int f = va_arg(mem_list,int);
      printf("%i \n",f);
    }
  }

  va_end(mem_list);
  return NULL;
}
```

However when I change to a float i.e.

```
float f1=1.0;
float f = va_arg(mem_list,float);
printf("%f \n",f);
```

It does not return the right value (the value is 0.00000). I am extremely confused at what is happening.

Answer (score 8):

In the context of a varargs call, `float` is actually promoted to `double`. Thus, you'll need to actually be pulling `double`s out, not `float`s.  This is the same reason that `%f` for `printf()` works with both `float` and `double`.

Comment: Good parallel to %f -> printf(), it indeed promotes floats.

Answer (score 3):

Since we are talking C++ here, you might want to use newer C++11 facilities.

I could suggest variadic templates, but it might be a bit too advanced, on the other hand to pass an arbitrary long list there now is [`std::initializer_list<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) where `T` is a simple type.

```
 void function(std::initializer_list<int> list);
```

It does not have many functions, just:

- `size()` which returns how many elements are in the list
- and `begin()` and `end()` which return iterators as usual

So you can actually do:

```
void function(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
    std::cout << "Gonna print " << list.size() << " integers:\n";

    bool first = true;
    for (int i: list) {
        if (first) { first = false; } else { std::cout << ", "; }
        std::cout << i;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

And then invoke it as:

```
int main() {
    function({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
}
```

which will print:

```
Gonna print 5 integers:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

In general in C++, stay away from the C-variadic. They are type-unsafe and full of gotchas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to port the code to objective-C as well, ergo, I am sticking to standard ANSI C.

Comment: I am sorry, I included the C++ tag as I was using a C++ compiler.