# Variadic function (va_arg) doesn't work with float, while printf does? What the difference is?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, variadic-functions

I just happened to have similar situation like in this question from two years:

[Variadic function (va_arg) doesn't work with float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270588/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float)

There is said that the problem is *promoting* float to double when we call things like

```
    va_arg(arg, float)
```

My question is at the end of this post, but first let's take a look at @Jack's answer below the question linked above:

```
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo(int n, ...)
{   
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, n);

    int c; 
    double val; 

    for(c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        val = va_arg(vl, double);
        printf("%f\n", val);
    }

    va_end(vl);
}


int main(void)
{
  foo(2, 3.3f, 4.4f);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.300000
4.400000
```

Now, if we change `val = va_arg(vl, double)` into `val = va_arg(vl, float)`, we will get (at least I get in MSVS 2012):

```
36893488147419103000.000000
2.162500
```

Let's go into my question now.

In this topic: [C/C++ va_list not returning arguments properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871235/c-c-va-list-not-returning-arguments-properly)
most voted answer and it's comment says that `printf` also *promotes* `float`'s to `double`'s.

But what is difference? If both of them promotes `float` into `double`, why `printf` writes values correctly, while `va_arg` gives us such a nasal demons?

Comment: What makes you think that `printf` tries to parse arguments, that it knows would have been promoted to `double`, as `float`? The `printf` function knows always to expect a `double` where a `float` would have been passed. Your function does not. This is the difference.

Comment: Thank you all for great answers! Now I get it, not only how it works, but even much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `printf` that promotes the float argument to `double`, it is *compiler* that does it. In other words, by the time your `va_arg` or `printf` or any other function with variable number of arguments gets the control, all the `float`s are already promoted to `double`s; the original `float`s are not available for retrieval.

The difference between `printf` and `va_arg` is that `printf` follows the rules set up by the standard, and request the parameter of a promoted type (i.e. `double`) when it sees the corresponding format specifier in the format string. Hence it successfully gets a `double` with the promoted value of the `float` in it, and produces the desired output.

On the other hand, when `va_arg` calls `val = va_arg(vl, float)` it ignores the promotion rule, and gets an invalid representation in return.

Comment: Note: this same issue applies if the argument to `printf()` was `char`, `short` or anything smaller than `int`: Need to use `int` with `va_arg()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now it is clear to me what was the cause of ruckus here.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments to variable argument functions gets special promotion rules.

The one relevant here is that passing a float as a variable argument gets promoted to a double. Meaning you cannot extract the argument as a float, as it has been passed as a double. This is done by the compiler, it has nothing to do with `printf`.

This means the code `val = va_arg(vl, float)` is not valid, as the argument is not a float, it's a double.
If you really need to deal with the passed in values as a float, at best you can do

```
float val = (float) va_arg(vl, double)
```

Note that the `%f` specifier for printf expects an argument of type `double` , not a `float`

Answer (score 3):

`printf` does not take arguments of type `float`.

The `"%f"` format specifier, for example, requires an argument of type `double`. `"%Lf"` requires an argument of type `long double`. There is no format that requires an argument of type `float` (which would be promoted to `double` anyway, not by `printf` itself but simply because of the semantics of calls to variadic functions).

So assuming `printf` is implemented in C, and that it uses the `<stdarg.h>` mechanisms to read its arguments, there is no invocation of `va_arg()` for type `float` in the implementation of `printf`.

Any variadic function that does attempt to invoke `va_arg()` for type `float` will have undefined behavior, since there can be no `float` arguments to such a function. `printf` works because it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

> But what is difference? If both of them promotes `float` into `double`, why `printf` writes values correctly, while `va_arg` gives us such a nasal demons?

There's no difference, except the fact (stated in the question itself), that `printf` is coded in a way to treat `float` as `double`. In other words, somewhere inside `printf`, when the format string contains information that there should be a floating point number, the function does `va_arg(vl, double)`, just like you did.