# own printf function does not work

Tags: c++, arguments, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write my own printf func in c++ for practive but I get the following runtime error and I can't figure out why :

```
Access violation reading location 0x33333333.
```

Here's the code :

```
void myPrintf(char* szStr, ...)
{
    va_list marker;
    va_start(marker, szStr);
    va_arg(marker, char*);
    char opCode;
    int nLen = istrlen(szStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i++)
    {
        if (szStr[i] != '%')
            cout << szStr[i];
        else
        {
            if (i + 1 < nLen)
            {
                opCode = szStr[i + 1];
                switch (opCode)
                {
                case 'd':
                    cout << va_arg(marker, int);
                    i += 2;
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    cout << va_arg(marker, float);
                    i += 2;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    cout << va_arg(marker, char*);
                    i += 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << '%';
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                cout << '%';
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I can't figure out why this happens,
could someone please tell me what did I do wrong ?

I'm calling the function with the following code :

```
myPrintf("%d %s %f", 5, "test", 10.1);
```

When the program crushed it shows me to this code :

```
static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL length(const _Elem *_First)
    {   // find length of null-terminated string
    return (*_First == 0 ? 0
        : _CSTD strlen(_First));
    }
```

Comment: So in your debugger, where does it crash? What code are you calling your function with?

Comment: Yes, but where does it crash? Step through it with a debugger.

Comment: Looks like you need to check your pointers for NULL.

Comment: If you can't use debugger, write some messages to console from critical places using `std::cerr` to find out where the error occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using visual studio and when it crashes it shows that the variable _First (from the function I've showed) is set to 0x33333333

Comment: If I were you, I'd like to use variadic templates or play with `std::tuple` to avoid using c-style `va_list`.

Comment: ok found that the error is coming from   cout << va_arg(marker, char*); but either without it, it prints the wrong numbers to the screen

Answer (score 2):

The first  `va_arg(marker, char*);` just after `va_start(marker, szStr);` should probably be removed, since it consumes the argument after `szStr` (i.e. the 5 in your example). The `va_start` macro is consuming the starting argument.

And `float` arguments are always passed as `double` (likewise `short` arguments are passed as `int`, etc...) so your `va_arg(marker, float);` should be a `va_arg(marker, double);`

Comment: doesn't it consume the string itself ? the "%d %s %f" ?

Comment: No.  `va_start()` sets `marker` to point at the first argument after `szStr`.  Every time `va_arg()` is called, it advances `marker` to the next argument and returns a pointer to where `marker` was previously pointing at. Thus the first `va_arg(char*)` is consuming the `5` parameter, so when `"%d"` is parsed, `va_arg(int)` is returning the `"Test"` parameter instead, and when `"%s"` is then parsed, `va_arg(char*)` is returning the `10.1` parameter, and so on.

Comment: I thought it consumes the first argument, my bad, also I've changed the i+=2 to i++ because I forgot it adds to i each iteration, everything works except the float is being printed as something else, in my case 10.1 is being printed as 4.17233e-008

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270588/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836118/variadic-function-va-arg-doesnt-work-with-float-while-printf-does-what-the